# npm - Distribute module for other developer

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

I have downloaded a specific module version including its dependencies by npm. Now I would like to distribute this module to other developers.

Sure, I simply could copy the whole module and copy it.
But how would I do this, if I want everyone to download exact the same packages as I did?
There should be kind of a mechanism by npm for this...

Note: I have installed the module globally.

Greets.

Answer (score 0):

First run:

```
npm list -g
```

This will output your installed packages, take note of the package name and version of the package you want to distribute.

Finally tell your collegues to run:

```
npm install package@version
```

To install the same version you have.

If you have modified something you may publish it with a different name or try to fork the repo on github if there is one, which is very usual.